# How to plot highest high & lowest low within a conditional timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My indicator plots buy/sell conditions (denoted by the vertical red/green bars). I'm trying to figure out how to plot the highest/lowest value when the condition is active. [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF1b6.png)

I've been trying using this code, however I think I am going about it in the wrong way.
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d89B.png)

```
GetHighestSince(condition, series=high) =>
    var float highestValueSince = na
    if condition
        highestValueSince := series
    highestValueSince

GetLowestSince(condition, series=low) =>
    var float lowestValueSince = na
    if condition
        lowestValueSince := series
    lowestValueSince


daysellhigh = GetHighestSince(sellcondition)
plot(daysellhigh, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=1, color=color.red)

daybuylow = GetLowestSince(buycondition)
plot(daybuylow, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=1, color=color.green)
```